# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.idea' / Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have this code, that reads several txt files in the same directory and then rights the name of the file inside each txt file. 
Here is my code:

```
arr=mypaht
for file in arr:
    file_name=file[24:31] + '_' + file[67:79]
    with open(file,'r+') as type:
        lines=type.read()
        print(lines)
```

Can someone tell me the reason to get this error? 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

PyCharm project contains an `.idea` folder where IDE stores per-project settings (it's hidden in the project tree by default). Most likely you didn't exclude directories from `mypaht` so the code tries to open `.idea` directory resulting in the error.

Use either `os.path.isfile` or `.is_file()` for `pathlib` to make sure only files are processed.